# Kohana events, where to place them

Tags: php, events, kohana

I'm trying to understand the event system of Kohana. The only thing i don't understand is, where to place the Event::add code.

It should be in a place where it is executed before any events are fired. Or am I missing something?

What i want to achieve is to construct a class that is available everywhere, but don't realy want to hack it into Kohana.

Can anyone cast a light on this?

Comment: I presume this is the PHP framework - http://kohanaphp.com/home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding in a [hook](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/hooks) with your Event::Add code.

From the documentation:

> The power of hooks mainly comes from the Events class. Hooks are loaded before any of the events are started so you can attach a hook to an event

Answer (score 0):

Usually Event::add() and Event::replace() are placed in the Hook constructor. 
Hooks are loaded before the first event of system ('system.ready') so you can add your callback to every system or custom event.